# What is the correct way to call a function from a string?

Tags: javascript

Is it okay to do the following:

```
// Response from an API as a string, that contains a function to call.
const stringFunc = 'myFunc({"Status":200,"Message":"This is a message"})';

function myFunc(obj) {
  console.log(obj);
}

function callBack(stringFn) {
  return Function.prototype.call(stringFn);
}

callBack(stringFunc);
```

Console logs:

```
{"Status":200,"Message":"This is a message"}
```

It seems to work just fine, but wanted to know if this was the correct way to go about this at all? Are there any better methods or unforeseen implications?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like [JSONP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about)

Comment: You can also call function by using eval :  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Answer (score 1):

Use [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) method.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <script>
        const stringFunc = 'myFunc({"Status":200,"Message":"This is a message"})';

        function myFunc(obj) {
            console.log(obj);
        }

        function callBack(stringFn) {
            return Function.prototype.call(stringFn);
        }

        eval(stringFunc);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why do you still have the callback() function though? Not needed if using eval(), right?

Comment: No need of callBack if your intended to call myFunc only

Comment: Note that using eval() or using any other way to execute code from a string is a serious security issue. When the string comes from an untrusted source, an attacker can execute anything in the context of your web page. You should not do that.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to `eval` you can use the `Function` constructor:

```
const stringFunc = 'myFunc({"Status":200,"Message":"This is a message"})';

function myFunc(obj) {
  console.log(obj);
}

const payloadFunc = new Function(stringFunc);
payloadFunc() //logs the object
```